# Drop rows in DataFrame by conditions on column values equal to None

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which there is a column "status" 
I try to delete all rows in which "status" columns contains None value.

I did like this :

```
oppty_oppline.dropna(subset = ['status'])
```

But The "None" values wasn't deleted .
I verify like this :

```
oppty_oppline.status.unique()
```

Result :

```
array(['Cancelled by ', 'Cancelled by Customer',
       'Account not selected', None,
       'Won - Deliver & Validate by ', 'Lost',
       'Won - Deliver & Validate by Partner',
       'Won-Deliver&Validate by ',
       'Cancelled by ', 'Won by another',
       'Won- Deliver and Validate by Partner',
       'Won – Deliver & Validate by Partner'], dtype=object)
```

I see that 'None' values is not considered as a string .

Any idea please to help me?

Thanks you

Comment: oppty_oppline= oppty_oppline[~oppty_oppline['status'].isnull()]

Comment: How working my solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `None` value it working nice:

```
a = np.array(['Cancelled by ', 'Cancelled by Customer',
       'Account not selected', None])

oppty_oppline = pd.DataFrame({'status':a})
print (oppty_oppline)
                  status
0          Cancelled by 
1  Cancelled by Customer
2   Account not selected
3                   None

df = oppty_oppline.dropna(subset = ['status'])
print (df)
                  status
0          Cancelled by 
1  Cancelled by Customer
2   Account not selected
```

But if string `None` need remove rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
a = np.array(['Cancelled by ', 'Cancelled by Customer',
       'Account not selected', 'None'])

oppty_oppline = pd.DataFrame({'status':a})
print (oppty_oppline)
                  status
0          Cancelled by 
1  Cancelled by Customer
2   Account not selected
3                   None

#not remove None, because string
df = oppty_oppline.dropna(subset = ['status'])
print (df)
0          Cancelled by 
1  Cancelled by Customer
2   Account not selected
3                   None
```

---

```
df = oppty_oppline[oppty_oppline.status != 'None']
print (df)
0          Cancelled by 
1  Cancelled by Customer
2   Account not selected
```